# Generation of electrostatic induction

Tags: capacitor, induction, inductive, electron, electrostatic

I need to generate a 500 volt electrostatic charge.

How can I do this?

I don't have a Van de Graaff generator.

What are some practical suggestions?

Basically I want to do an experiment in which I need to induce charges on a plate. One side positive and another side negative.  What are some practical suggestions for me?

One approach is to place a metal plate inside a high voltage capacitor. How practical is this approach? The potential between the two sides of the metal plate should be at least 30 to 40 volts.

Comment: I think a Kelvin water dropper can reach 500 volts pretty easily. That's something you can make in a basic workshop in a few hours.

Comment: Wait, I read it again and... do you want 500 volts or 30 to 40 volts? One of these is much easier than the other.

Comment: @Hearth 300-400V maybe?

Comment: @Hearth, I need to produce 500 voltage at the parallel plates so that I can safely get atleast if 30 to 40 volt potential between the two sides of induced metal. So basically at the core I need to produce 30 to 40 volts of potential between the two sides of a charge induced metal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If your target is a metal plate, you'll get 0 V across it at all times. Draw a diagram, labelling what conducts and what doesn't. Are you building an electrophorus? Charge moves, but voltage stays at 0 V due to induction.

Comment: 500V isn't really VdG territory. More like old camera flash territory.